# Error with classic asp database connection after migration of website from IIS6 to IIS7

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, iis-7, asp-classic, adodb

I have a classic asp site which has the following database connection:

```
<%
set objConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=123.456.789.012;Database=mydatabase;Uid=myuser;Pwd=123xyz;"
objConnection.Open
%>
```

The site has just been moved from a Windows 2003 server running IIS6 to a Windows 2008 server running IIS7 (both using MSSQL 2005 Express database) and it now gives an error message:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]Invalid connection.
/inc/dbconnection.asp, line 4
```

I'm assuming it's because there's a different driver with IIS7?  What would be the updated connection string to get this to work - I've googled and just not found anything that works or makes sense to me (I'm at the edge of my understanding here to be honest!)?

Many thanks for any pointers folks...

Comment: you might have to add the instance name to the servername http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843864/asp-connections-to-sql-2008-named-instance

Comment: Did you try to disable Windows Firewall or add SQL server to allowed program list? When I activated Windows Firewall, I can not connect to sql database. So I added SQL Server to allowed programs list, and my application worked..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to call the ODBC driver for SQL Server, which was traditionally provided with [MDAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937729.aspx).  Rather than try to troubleshoot that in IIS7, I would probably use one of the [SQL Server Native Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms130828%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) drivers, as in:

```
"Driver={SQL Native Client};..."
```

or

```
"Provider=SQLNCLI10;..."
```

Some history can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx), and other connection string options and info can be found at the great site, [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If the database is on the same server as the website, and the MSSQL 2005 Express database isn't a named instance, you could use the following Data Source:

```
<%
set objConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=mydatabase; User ID=myuser;"
objConnection.Open
%>
```

If you've installed MSSQL 2005 Express locally using the default instance name of "sqlexpress" then you'll need to use the following Data Source

```
<%
set objConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=.\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog=mydatabase; User ID=myuser;"
objConnection.Open
%>
```